# Profiling system start-up

Tags: macos, startup

How can one find start-up bottlenecks on macOS? On Linux I normally do `systemd-analyze blame`, which shows the initialization times of all services - is there a `launchd` counterpart?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  What problem are you trying to solve?  Right now, you've written an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) type of question.

Comment: I have two user accounts on my mac. The time between entering the password and getting to the desktop is much larger for one of those two accounts than for the other. The suspicion is that certain launchd services take too much time to start, so I would like to test this theory and maybe even find the culprit in the process. Also, it would be in general helpful to know, whether a startup profiling tool exists, in order to debug similar problems in the future.